# how do I add multiple modal boxes

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on a website and i have the basis of my modal box but i want to have more than just one. I've seen people just copying and pasting the same javascript code for all of the modal boxes but i was wondering if there was a simpler method, here's my code

```js
// just to pretty up the box and add come color

const box = document.querySelector(".box");
box.style.display = "none";
const header = document.querySelector(".header");
const close = document.querySelector("#box-close");
const open = document.querySelector(".button");


close.addEventListener("click", closeBox);
open.addEventListener("click", openBox);
header.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);


function mouseDown(i){

    
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);  // it listens to see if the mouse is clicking down on the div, when it does, it calls the function"drag"
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", letGo);   // it listens to see if the mosue isn't clicking anymore, when it does, it calls the function "letGo"

    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowWidth =window.innerWidth;
    let previousX = i.clientX;                   //make a variable called previousX that stores the data of your current mouse X position
    let previousY = i.clientY;                   //make a variable called previousY that stores the data of your current mouse Y postion

    function drag(i){                            //what happens when the program detects a mouse click
        let currentX = previousX - i.clientX;      // make s a variable called currentX that stores the x distance that your mouse traveled
        let curretY = previousY - i.clientY;       //makes a variable called currentY that stores the Y distance that your mouse traveled
        const bounds = box.getBoundingClientRect();   // gets the boundaries of the box object and their postions on the browser windows

        if(bounds.left <= 0 ){                                //if the left bound of the box is touching the left side of the screen 
            box.style.top = bounds.top - curretY + "px";      //allow for the updating in the y direction
            box.style.left = bounds.left + 5 +"px";           //bounce off the box 5 pixels to the left
            previousY = i.clientY;                          //reset the y value to allow up and down movement
            console.log("left");
        }
        else if(bounds.right >= windowWidth){                      //does the same thing as the last if statement but if the right bound of the box is touching the right side of the scrren
            box.style.top = bounds.top - curretY +"px";
            box.style.left = bounds.left - 5 +"px";
            previousY = i.clientY;
            console.log("right");
        }
        else if(bounds.bottom >= windowHeight){                       //same thing as the last but if the box touches the bottom
            box.style.left = bounds.left - currentX + "px";
            box.style.top = bounds.top - 5 + "px";
            previousX = i.clientX;
            console.log("down");
        }
        else if(bounds.top <= 0){                                 //same thign as the last but if the box touches the top
            box.style.left = bounds.left - currentX + "px"; 
            box.style.top = bounds.top+  5 + "px";
            previousX = i.clientX;
            console.log("up");
        }
        else{                                               //else if 
            box.style.left = bounds.left - currentX + "px"; //takes the value of the left side of the box and subtracts the difference in distance in pixels
            box.style.top = bounds.top - curretY + "px";    //does the same as the previous line but for the Y/top of the box
            previousX = i.clientX;   //these two lines reset the values of previous x&y so that your current mouse positon is always updating
            previousY = i.clientY;
        }
    }
    function letGo(){                                       // whe the mouse it let go
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);      //stop listening to the mouse positions so the window doesnt stick to your mouse
        window.removeEventListener("mouseDown", letGo);
    }
}
function openBox(){
    if (box.style.display === "none") {
        box.style.display = "block";
    }
    console.log("open");
}
function closeBox(){
    if(box.style.display !== "none"){
        box.style.display = "none";
    }
    console.log("close");
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    height: 280px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 9;  
}
.header{
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    background: rgb(69, 161, 211);
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;      
    cursor: move;  
}
.box-buttons{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    right: 0em;
    top: 0em;
}
.operation-button{
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 248px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="f*$#.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="buttonone" class="button">click me</button>
    <div id="boxone" class="box">
        <div class="header">header
            <div class="box-buttons">
                <div id="box-close" class="operation-button">&times</div>
                <div id="box-maximize" class="operation-button">max</div>
                <div id="box-minimize" class="operation-button">min</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="resize"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="fuck.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

heres the part that i'm worried about, with just one modal box, it works really well but as soon as i try to add another one, it fails completely. i though that because it using the class of box and all that it would work since both modals would have the same box class with different ids to differentiate but it just didn't work. i don't really want to copy and paste this since i'm going to have more than 2 modal boxes so i don't want to have 1000 lines if possible

Comment: Are you calling the Modal box by it's unique ID, or are you calling it via the similar class? If you call via unique ID, you can call the box accordingly. If you are using a class and that class is on each box, how will it know which to call? So it will only call the first one.

Comment: Alternatively; you'd need something that loops through each box class. The way you have it in your code, it is only going to find and latch on to the first box class it finds. That is why it fails after the first box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple popups you are going to have to approach the issue differently. You want to be able to call an object method that creates a new instance of a pop-up so you have an infinite number available at your finger tips to call whenever you need them. This is why I suggest you make a constructor (think of it like a blueprint) called Pop-up that you can call at any time to create a new pop-up instance. You can then use the setContent method to pass whatever content you want in the actual pop-up modal. I have prepared a codepen  showing you how to do this:

https://codepen.io/klaurtar/pen/YzqzKRK

Here is the HTML:

```
<button id="pop-up">Button</button>
```

Here is some basic css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}



.pop-up {
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  
/*  Positioning  */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.exit-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Everytime the button is pressed a new pop-up instance is created in JavaScript.

```
  const button = document.body.querySelector('#pop-up');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const popup = popUpManager.createPopUp();
  
  popup.setContent('<h1>Hello from the popup!</h1>');
})

const popUpManager = (function popUpManager() {
  const $popUpManager = document.createElement('div');
  $popUpManager.className = "pop-up_manager";
  
  document.body.append($popUpManager);
  
  return {
    createPopUp: () => {
      const popup = new Popup();
      const $popup = popup.getPopup();
      $popUpManager.append($popup);
      return popup;
    }
  }
})();

class Popup{
  constructor() {
    this.$popup = document.createElement('div');
    this.$popup.className = 'pop-up';
    this.$popup.innerHTML = '<div class="exit-button">X</div><div class="body"></div>';
    
    this.$exitButton = this.$popup.querySelector('.exit-button');
    this.$body = this.$popup.querySelector('.body');
    
    this.setUpListeners();
  }
  
  getPopup() {
    return this.$popup;
  }
  
  setContent($content) {
    if (typeof $content === 'string') {
      this.$body.innerHTML = $content;
    } else {
      this.$body.appendChild($content);
    }
  }
  
  close() {
    this.$popup.remove();
  }
  
  setUpListeners() {
    this.$exitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.close();
    });
  }
}
```